# How to configure toolchain in Bazel

Tags: arm, cross-compiling, bazel, toolchain

We plan to use Bazel to cross-compile for different arch target and we get some problems about toolchain:

As per the [docs](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/0.24.0/tutorial/cc-toolchain-config.html#configuring-the-c-toolchain), we configured the toolchain as:

```
toolchain_include_directories_feature = feature(
        name = "toolchain_include_directories",
        enabled = True,
        flag_sets = [
            flag_set(
                actions = [
                    "ACTION_NAMES.assemble",
                    "ACTION_NAMES.preprocess_assemble",
                    "ACTION_NAMES.linkstamp_compile",
                    "ACTION_NAMES.c_compile",
                    "ACTION_NAMES.cpp_compile",
                    "ACTION_NAMES.cpp_header_parsing",
                    "ACTION_NAMES.cpp_module_compile",
                    "ACTION_NAMES.cpp_module_codegen",
                    "ACTION_NAMES.lto_backend",
                    "ACTION_NAMES.clif_match",
                ],
                flag_groups = [
                    flag_group(
                        flags = [
                             "-isystem",
                             "/opt/buildtools/sdk/usr/include",
                        ],
                    ),
                ],
            ),
        ],
    )
```

and we get the error:

```
ERROR: /home/project/aa/BUILD:1:1: undeclared inclusion(s) in rule '//aa:mylib':
this rule is missing dependency declarations for the following files included by 'aa/source/export.c':
  '/opt/buildtools/sdk/usr/include/stdc-predef.h'
```

Any ideas, thanks.

Added: the environment info

```
LSB Version:    n/a
Distributor ID: SUSE
Description:    SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 12 SP4
Release:        12.4
Codename:       n/a
4.12.14-94.41-default #1 SMP Wed Oct 31 12:25:04 UTC 2018 (3090901) x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Bazel version: 0.24.1
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create the toolchain config with `create_cc_toolchain_config_info`, don't forget to set up its `cxx_builtin_include_directories` parameter by adding the usual include paths as well, like

```py
def _impl(ctx):
    #  [...]
    cxx_builtin_include_directories = [
        "/opt/buildtools/sdk/usr/include/",
        "/usr/include",
    ]

    return [
        cc_common.create_cc_toolchain_config_info(
            cxx_builtin_include_directories = cxx_builtin_include_directories,
            #  [...]
        ),
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Also ACTION_NAMES in the actions list should not be enclosed with quotes. See this: https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/pull/7673